# onClick like button likes all objects in array React JS

Tags: reactjs

I'm super new to web development but I'm trying to implement a like button to an API array of the mars rover images in react js. The problem I'm having is when I click the like button for one of my images all of the like buttons click. I've tried using id's, classNames, and keys for my button but nothing seems to be working. Any help would be appreciated :)

```
class Rover extends React.Component {
  state = {
      loading: true,
      images: [],
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
      const url = 'https://api.nasa.gov/mars-photos/api/v1/rovers/curiosity/photos?sol=1000&page=2&api_key='
      const response = await fetch(url);
      const data= await response.json();
      this.setState({ images: data.photos, loading: false });
      console.log(this.state);
  }

  render() {
      if (this.state.loading) {
          return <div>loading...</div>;
      }
      if (!this.state.images) {
          return <div>didn't find image</div>
      }

        return (
          <IconContext.Provider value={{ color: '#a9b3c1', size: 64 }}>
            <RoverSection>
              <RoverWrapper>
                <RoverHeading>Mars Rover</RoverHeading>
                <div>
                    {this.state.images.map((image, idx) => (
                    <div className={`some-image-${idx}`} key={`some-image${idx}`}>
                      <RoverContainer>
                          <RoverCard to='/'>
                            <RoverCardInfo>
                              <RoverCardID>Photo ID: {image.id}</RoverCardID>
                              <RoverCardFeatures>
                                <Img src={image.img_src} />
                                <RoverCardFeature>{image.rover.name} Rover</RoverCardFeature>
                                <RoverCardFeature>{image.camera.full_name}</RoverCardFeature>
                                <RoverCardFeature>{image.earth_date}</RoverCardFeature>
                              </RoverCardFeatures>
                              <Button primary id={image.id} className={`some-button-${idx}`} onClick={() => {
                                this.setState({
                                  isLiked: !this.state.isLiked
                                })
                              }}>{this.state.isLiked ? <FaHeart/> : <FaRegHeart/>}</Button>
                            </RoverCardInfo>
                          </RoverCard>
                        </RoverContainer>
                      </div>
                    ))}
                   </div>
                </RoverWrapper>
              </RoverSection>
            </IconContext.Provider>
        );
      }
    }

export default Rover
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mapping through all of the images (you have an array of images); However, you do not have an array for your likes you just have a single boolean value. You need to create an array for your likes of equal size to your image array and then use the same index (you can get the current index in your map (you already did an named it idx))

Your initial like state should be similar to:

```
 async componentDidMount() {
      const url = 'https://api.nasa.gov/mars-photos/api/v1/rovers/curiosity/photos?sol=1000&page=2&api_key='
      const response = await fetch(url);
      const data= await response.json();
      this.setState({ images: data.photos, isLiked:new Array(data.photos.length).fill(false), loading: false });
      console.log(this.state);
  }
```

and then in you component

```
this.setState((current)=>{
  const newState={...current};
  const isLiked = newState.isLiked;
  isLiked[idx] = !isLiked[idx];
  return {
    ...newState,
    isLiked:[...isLiked]
  }
})
```

and

```
{this.state.isLiked[idx] ? <FaHeart/> : <FaRegHeart/>}
```

Comment: @Mitch sure thing welcome to the SO community!

Answer (score 0):

lets say this is your image array:

```
this.state.images = [{id : 0, img : "img1"} ,{id : 1 , img : "img2"} ,{id : 2, img : "img3"}  ]
```

now say you want to like img1 , when you click like on img1, dont you think that you need to only save img1 as liked image. you can do it by modifying the images array object. if you dont want to change data in your original image object,you can keep another array/object map with id and their like status ( you can keep all or you can only push the liked ones.

now when you click on any like button on image , call the function ( also bind it in constructor)

```
onClick = {(e)=> {this.handleLikeClick(image)}}
```

and in function handleLikeClick

```
handleLikeClick(image){
    let copyImages = [...this.state.images]
    this.state.images.forEach((img) => {
         if(img.id === image.id) {
            img.liked= !img.liked;
         }
    });
    this.setState({
       images :copyImages 
    })
}
```

now whenever you are in render , instead of just checking isLIked, you can check the liked property in image object.